# Highlight specific words with CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, regex

Is it possible to highlight (or do something to) specific words, or regular expressions?

<strike>I'm going for a no-javascript solution here, but it might not be possible.</strike>

Comment: Do you need to handle text that crosses element boundaries? For example, searching for "foobar" in `<p>foo<b>bar</b></p>`?

Comment: @Tim Down, no, it's all just in a big div with no formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need JavaScript to do this. I recommend using a `strong` tag rather than span but either will work. This will replace all first words. You can replace the `^\w` with whatever is meaningful.

```
$('a').each(function() {
    var me = $(this);
    me.html( me.text().replace(/(^\w+)/,'<strong>$1</strong>') );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

No it's not, you would have to use spans.

Answer (score 0):

Best you can hope for is encapsulating the words in a span with a class to do some sort of highlighting. You could do this server side based on search results by using a simple regex compare to replace the searched for string with that string again wrapped with a span. It is not possible, so far as I know, to do this solely with CSS.